# iven $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ U is convex and $||D_f(x)||<1$ for every $x\in U$. $g$ is diffeomorphism.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  U is convex and $||D_f(x)||<1$ for every $x\in U$.
Setting $g(x)=x+f(x)$ prove $g$ is diffeomorphism.
I've manged to prove the $g$ is one to one and no idea how to prove $g^{-1}\in C^1$

Comment: Can you use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)?

Comment: I thought about it but didn't see how to use it

Comment: Well, the theorem tells you that $g^{-1}$ must be $C^1$.

Comment: I agree but how can I know that the $D_f(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: Oh nvm because $g$ is one to one it must happen no?

Comment: How did you prove that $g$ is one to one, if not by using the idea from my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110119/discussion-between-ron-kurman-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\|D_g(x)\| = \|I + D_f(x)\| \geq \|I\| - \|D_f(x)\|$.